# How can I use Guava's immutable collections with mybatis?

Tags: java, quarkus, guava, mybatis

I tried making return type ImmutableList and selecting a bunch of IDs from a table, but of course mybatis does not know how to do that and throws exception:

```
org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating class com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:88)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:53)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.create(DefaultObjectFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.convertToDeclaredCollection(MapperMethod.java:173)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:154)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
    at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy76.getAllIds(Unknown Source)
    at org.acanthite.services.UtilityService.getAllIds(UtilityService.java:98)
    at org.acanthite.services.UtilityService_ClientProxy.getAllIds(Unknown Source)
    at org.acanthite.resources.UtilityResource.ids(UtilityResource.java:77)
    at org.acanthite.resources.UtilityResource$quarkusrestinvoker$ids_8602df045ce9b7e168a75788bbd936486ed83b98.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.factory.DefaultObjectFactory.instantiateClass(DefaultObjectFactory.java:66)
    ... 22 more
```

Here is my mapper's XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "https://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="org.acanthite.repository.UtilityRepository">
    <select id="getAllIds" resultType="integer">
        select id from utility;
    </select>
</mapper>
```

The mapper interface:

```java
@Mapper
public interface UtilityRepository {
  ImmutableList<Integer> getAllIds();
}
```

And how I use it:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UtilityService {
  private final UtilityRepository repository;
  
  public ImmutableList<Integer> getAllIds() {
    return repository.getAllIds();
  }
}
```

Is there a library or workaround teach mybatis how to instantiate Guava's immutable collections (or basically any other non-java collection)?

Comment: What code are you trying to run?

Comment: @SolomonUcko, I've updated the original post

Comment: What JDK version are you using? There are specific reason to "any other non-java collection"?

Comment: I use JDK 17, though I don't see how it changes something. I just want to use immutable collections. I don't like defensive copying all over the my code, or just relying on "no one will mutate it after passing to constructor", or relying on the actual implementation of List<T> is being immutable. I want to explicitly declare things immutable and don't bother myself with redundant work or mutability assumptions.

Comment: "I just want to use immutable collections" Right! Since JDK 9 there is native immutable collections, just use them!

Comment: @ClaudioWeiler, yes I know that. But the problem is that I cannot be explicit about it. All I have is the `List` interface which cannot tell me that a collection that I've got a reference to is immutable.

Comment: Hum! Understand. You want a contractual immutable collection.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the key parts of the code:

```
  public Object execute(SqlSession sqlSession, Object[] args) {
    Object result;
    switch (command.getType()) {
      // ...
      case SELECT:
        if (method.returnsVoid() && method.hasResultHandler()) {
          executeWithResultHandler(sqlSession, args);
          result = null;
        } else if (method.returnsMany()) {
          result = executeForMany(sqlSession, args);
        } else if (method.returnsMap()) {
          result = executeForMap(sqlSession, args);
        } else if (method.returnsCursor()) {
          result = executeForCursor(sqlSession, args);
        } else {
          Object param = method.convertArgsToSqlCommandParam(args);
          result = sqlSession.selectOne(command.getName(), param);
          if (method.returnsOptional() && (result == null || !method.getReturnType().equals(result.getClass()))) {
            result = Optional.ofNullable(result);
          }
        }
        break;
      // ...
    }
    if (result == null && method.getReturnType().isPrimitive() && !method.returnsVoid()) {
      throw new BindingException("Mapper method '" + command.getName()
          + "' attempted to return null from a method with a primitive return type (" + method.getReturnType() + ").");
    }
    return result;
  }
```

```
  private <E> Object executeForMany(SqlSession sqlSession, Object[] args) {
    List<E> result;
    Object param = method.convertArgsToSqlCommandParam(args);
    if (method.hasRowBounds()) {
      RowBounds rowBounds = method.extractRowBounds(args);
      result = sqlSession.selectList(command.getName(), param, rowBounds);
    } else {
      result = sqlSession.selectList(command.getName(), param);
    }
    // issue #510 Collections & arrays support
    if (!method.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(result.getClass())) {
      if (method.getReturnType().isArray()) {
        return convertToArray(result);
      }
      return convertToDeclaredCollection(sqlSession.getConfiguration(), result);
    }
    return result;
  }
```

```
  private <E> Object convertToDeclaredCollection(Configuration config, List<E> list) {
    Object collection = config.getObjectFactory().create(method.getReturnType());
    MetaObject metaObject = config.newMetaObject(collection);
    metaObject.addAll(list);
    return collection;
  }
```

https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/zh/jacoco/org.apache.ibatis.binding/MapperMethod.java.html

Unfortunately, it seems like the only options are to use the original list, convert into a new collection using no-arg-constructor + `addAll`, or convert into an array. Therefore, I would do this:

```
@Mapper
public interface UtilityRepository {
  List<Integer> getAllIds();
}

@ApplicationScoped
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UtilityService {
  private final UtilityRepository repository;
  
  public ImmutableList<Integer> getAllIds() {
    return ImmutableList.copyOf(repository.getAllIds());
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that's what I do currently, but I thought there maybe some kind of collection handler interface or function that I could override or something like that to make seamless.

Comment: @acanthite Unfortunately, not as far as I can tell.

Comment: @acanthite Nevermind, `executeWithResultHandler` would still need a wrapper.

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it seem like wrapping into `ImmutableList.copyOf` is the only solution as of now. Also, I filed an [issue](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/2877) to mybatis github repo. 

Thanks for your time!